# WPF - how to change animations duration while app is running

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to support accessibility (for people with different disabilities), so I need to allow the user to disable the animations in my WPF application.
So in such case they chose to disable (by some button), I need to set the "duration" of all the storyboards in my resources dictionary to 0.

So my code find all the resources that are Storyboard, and when I try to change their duration to 0, I got this reasonable error:
"***Cannot set a property on object 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard' because it is in a read-only state***"

I would love to hear ideas how to overcome it. Thanks.

I can make it configurable ("AccessibilityMode = "true") and then register to Startup event of App.cs and load different dictionary with duration=0 in each storyboard, but I still want to know How can I do that after app startup. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you should post your code

Comment: in your resources dictionary you should set Duration="{Binding}"